# show image on hover does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider

Im using flexslide to show some images, now I want to show the next/prev image as a thumbnail while hovering over the next and prev arrows.
But if I use an image as thubnail the mouse over effect stop working, but if i use a CSS border, the hover works just fine.

I have created a fiddle where the prev arrow hovers an image(that dosent work) and the next arrow hover a simple border( works ) 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h4krS/21/)

```
#carousel .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-prev {
    background: url('http://cmbstaging.dreamhosters.com/assets/images/arrow-left.png') no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 39px;
    left: -36px;
}
```

I tried to change the display:block, to display:inline-block. But that didn't do the work.
Any tips ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a z-index to the arrows.

```
.flex-direction-nav,
.flex-direction-nav * {
    z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```

Comment: Worked out of the box! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

When you move your mouse over the arrow button it will trigger the hover enter function which fades in your thumbnail.  Since your thumbnail is now on top of the arrow and right underneath your mouse pointer, as soon as you move the mouse again it immediately registers that you are hovering over the thumbnail and therefore no longer are hovering over the arrow.  This triggers your hover leave function which fades your thumbnail back out again.  This is why it keeps flickering.

**One way** to fix this is to use css option `pointer-events: none` on your thumbnail image, this will make it so your thumbnail image elements completely ignore the mouse.  NOTE, however, that IE does not support this (because they actually support the standard, and the standard says that pointer-events option is only for SVG elements).  So if you try this method, it will work for just about every browser except IE.

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h4krS/27/) demonstrating this on your previous arrow. (Note: does not work on IE)

**Another way** is to actually make a new transparent element that is on top of both your arrow and thumbnail image.  Hook your mouse hover event functions to that new transparent element and your result will appear as if a mouse hover over the arrow makes the thumbnail appear on top.

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h4krS/29/) demonstrating this on your previous arrow.  What I did was add a new element to the `flex-direction-nav` and then set the CSS for it to this:

```
a.prevhover {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 39px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you for the very good explanation. I didn't think of the double hover effect that's inside the image.
And actually never heard of pointer-events:none :) Thank you thank you